# How to Add Wordpress Filter to add_filter to next_post_link

Tags: wordpress-theming

How can I add the `PARAMETERS` to this WP `function next_post_link()`.

```
add_filter ('next_post_link', 'new_next_post_link');
function new_next_post_link ($args) {

in_same_cat ??????

return $args;
}
```

I need to change it via FILTER cause I cant change it in the Theme. I tried this.

```
add_filter ('next_post_link', 'new_next_post_link');
function new_next_post_link ($args) {

$args = "Hello World";

return $args;
}
```

This works, so I need to know how to change "Hello World" into next_post_link('%link', 'Next post in category', TRUE);

Cheers,
Denis

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to. the third parameter is `in_same_cat` (bool). by default it is set as false.

```
<?php next_post_link($format, $link, true); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link

Comment: Hey Samuel, thanks for your answer, but I cant/want change the theme. I need to do it in my child theme functions.php.